# Add the curly bracket of the rcases environment in the enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, brackets, cases

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item text
  \item text
  \item[-] text
  \item[-] text
  \item text
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add a curly bracket next to the two items with the minus symbol. Something like the curly bracket of the rcases environment, or a square bracket, if possible (I'd like to see which one looks better). I'd like to put some text next to the bracket, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

with use of `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item text
  \item text
  \item[-] \tikzmarknode{a}{text}
  \item[-] \tikzmarknode{b}{text}
  \item text
 \end{enumerate}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw (a.east) -- ++ (0.2,0) |- (b)
                                node[pos=0.25, right] {some text};
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item text
  \item text
  \item[-] \tikzmarknode{c}{text}
  \item[-] \tikzmarknode{d}{text}
  \item text
 \end{enumerate}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture,
      decoration=brace]\draw[decorate]  (c.north east) --
                                node[right=1mm] {some text}
                                        (d.south east);
\end{document}
```

if text in items is not equal length, than you need to adopt coordinates accordingly to the longest one. for example

```
\tikz[overlay,remember picture,
      decoration=brace]\draw[decorate]  (c.north-| d.east) --
                                node[right=1mm] {some text}
                                        (d.south east);
```

if the text in `tikzmarknode{d}{...}` is longer than in `tikzmarknode{c}{...}`.